# Nativescript core cameraplus with Ml-kit problem taking photos

Tags: javascript, camera, nativescript, firebase-mlkit

I'm using a NativeScript core OCR with cameraplus plugin and ml-kit from firebase. I have this code for the view:

```
<Page navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" xmlns:Cam="@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus">

    <StackLayout>

        <Cam:CameraPlus 
            id="camPlus"
            height="70%"
            width="70%"     
            showCaptureIcon="false"
            showGalleryIcon="false"
            showToggleIcon="false"       
            showFlashIcon="false"
            confirmPhotos="false" 
            debug="true">
        </Cam:CameraPlus>

    <Button text="test" tap="onCapture" />

    </StackLayout>

</Page>
```

and this for the js :

```
const HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");
const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
const imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");
const CameraPlus = require("@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus");

exports.onNavigatingTo = function (args) {
    page = args.object;
    mv = page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
};

exports.onCapture = function() {

    camera = page.getViewById("camPlus");
    camera.takePicture({ saveToGallery: false }) 
        .then(function (imageAsset) {

          const source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
          source.fromAsset(imageAsset).
               then((imageSource) => {
               getTextFromPhoto(imageSource);
          });

          }).catch(function (err) {
               console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
          });

};
```

I'm having an error:

> System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

when I keep only the method:

```
camera.takePicture({ saveToGallery: false })
```

it works so there must be a js problem. The idea is to connect that photo with ml-kit (I have to use cameraplus plugin because It needs to be integrated instead of launching the camera app like in camera (basic) plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the [documentation](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus#events) carefully, the return value of `takePicture` method is `void` not a `Promise`. You must listen to the `photoCapturedEvent` on `CameraPlus` component.

**Update:**

If you are using NativeScript Core, you will have to add the listener programatically. Doing it from XML may not work.

Comment: I tried with photoCapturedEvent="photoCapturedEvent" inside the Cam:CameraPlus, but It sems thar never fired with exports.photoCapturedEvent = function() {
    alert('Test');
};

Comment: Try adding the event listener programatically on `CameraPlus` / `Page`'s loaded event.

Comment: oh! ok that works, So I supouse that it disapear on CameraPlus element draw and the event must to be reengaged. Lots of thanks :)